# Multiple/dynamic flexsliders for photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, entries, image-galleries

I'd like to run multiple flexsliders on a page, but in JS, there's only a reference to `#carousel` and `#slider` tags. I can use {count} or some other variable next to id to create a unique `id`, but not quite sure how to execute in JS so that this works dynamically no matter how many sliders client loads. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the EE/HTML template code:

```
{playa_projects var_prefix="playafield"}
    <?php $count = $i++; ?>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" title="{playafield:studies_caption}">{playafield:title}</a></li>
    <div id="inline-<?php echo $count; ?>" style="display: none;">
        <div id="slider<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider slider-js">
            <div class="flex-heading">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>{playafield:project_name}</h2>
                </div>
                {playafield:studies_outline_block var_prefix="nested_matrix"}
                    {if nested_matrix:content_1}
                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                            <h3>Project Size</h3>
                            {nested_matrix:content_1}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    {if nested_matrix:content_2}
                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                            <h3>Project Cost</h3>
                            {nested_matrix:content_2}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    {if nested_matrix:content_3}
                        <div class="col-md-2 project-name">
                            <h3>Project Use</h3>
                            {nested_matrix:content_3}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                {/playafield:studies_outline_block}
            </div>
            <ul class="slides">
                {playafield:studies_image_gallery}
                    <li><img src="{playafield:url}" /></li>
                {/playafield:studies_image_gallery}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel<?php echo $count; ?>" class="flexslider carousel-js">
            <ul class="slides">
                {playafield:studies_image_gallery}
                    <li><img src="{playafield:url}" /></li>
                {/playafield:studies_image_gallery}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{/playa_projects}
```

Here's the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {         

    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({
        width     : 800,
        height    : 800,
        autoSize   : false,
        autoHeight : true,
        autoResize  : true,
        scrollOutside  : true,
        aspectRatio : false,
        maxWidth  : '90%',
        fitToView    : false,
        scrolling : 'auto',
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        helpers:  {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        },

        beforeShow:function(el){

            $(".carousel-js").each(function() {
                var id = this.id;
                var subNav = id.substr(-1);

                jQuery('#' + id).flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: false,
                    slideshow: false,
                    itemWidth: 210,
                    itemMargin: 5,
                    prevText: "",
                    nextText: "",
                    asNavFor: '#slider' + subNav
                    //move: 2,
                    //startAt: 0,
                });
            });

            $(".slider-js").each(function() {
                var id = this.id;
                var carousel = id.substr(-1);

                jQuery('#' + id).flexslider({
                    animation: "fade",
                    controlNav: false,
                    animationLoop: false,
                    slideshow: false,
                    prevText: "",
                    nextText: "",
                    sync: "#carousel" + carousel,
                    //startAt: 0,
                    start: function(slider){
                      $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                });
            });

            //jQuery.fancybox.inner.resize();
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery.fancybox.reposition();
                jQuery.fancybox.inner.resize(); 
            },300); 
        }

    });     

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy. Just create your unique ID's as you suggested, but give each carousel a common class.

```
$('.carousel').each(function() {

    // this will loop over each carousel
    var this_carousel_id = this.id;

    // do your carousel setup here with your id!

});
```

Comment: I've tried this a few different ways with no luck. Any other hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you apply the `class="carousel"` to your slider element (the one you give an ID to)? If so, use the `each()` function and just `console.log(this.id)`. Are you getting the expected output in your developer console?

Comment: I got the output, and attached screenshot...along with my revised code. Definitely looks like I'm getting closer, but still haven't resolved.

Comment: Did you prepend your ids with hashtags? jQuery won't understand `("my_id_1").carousel()` but it will `("#my_id_1").carousel()`. So make sure `var my_id = "#" + this.id`;

Comment: I updated my code. I was able to get the first ten slides working, however think something to do with `substr` isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: `"10".substr(-1)` resolves to '0'.  Is the value of `$count` ever equal to 0?  looks like it might start counting at 1.